# How to save data between activity change and on app startup restore old data?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a `tableLayout` in which a user can dynamicaly add rows during run time. But when I change the activity and then switch back to it all data is lost.

In my class I have an arraylist which I fill with data in `onCreate()`. 
I am thinking of `@Overriting` the `onSaveInstanceState()` and I am thinking on adding to the `savedInstanceState` `Bundle` the arraylist but there is no putArrayList.

After that i will call it in onRestore by overriting it and with a for loop fill again the rows that with data from the `ArrayList`

Please give me an opinion how to do this?

Comment: Here's a link to an answer that suggests using Parceable objects: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3470211/379245

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways in fact.

1. Choose an other way of storing you data (parcelable)
2. Go for static, see [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566921/androidpassing-a-hash-map-between-activities/)
3. Save data to SQLite
4. Save data to SharedPrefs (e.g. Settings). Although this might not be the perfect way for ArrayLists.